# Transfer Live Photos to another folder on Macbook

Tags: photos, photos.app

I am able to upload Live Photos from my iPhone to Macbook. I am able to view the Live Photos within Photos.app. However, when I transfer a Live Photo from 'Photos Library.photoslibrary' to another location only a still .jpg is saved.

How can I transfer Live Photos to other locations on my Macbook - keeping them Live?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Macworld.com](http://www.macworld.com/article/3072674/iphone-ipad/how-to-export-a-live-photos-movie-into-os-x.html):

> Option-drag an image into the Finder or select File > Export > Export
>   Unmodified Original For [X] Photo(s) are both the unmodified JPEG and
>   the associated MOV retrieved.
>
> You can also use the Image Capture app with an iPhone connected via
>   USB, select the iPhone, choose Live Photos images, and then import
>   them, and both the JPEG and MOV for each image are transferred.

Comment: Modifying originals is a terrible default. Good answer though :-)